# Use custom field as tag slug

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I am trying to replace 'tag-slug' with a custom field value, so it will automatically pull the tags that match the custom field 'my-tag-slug'

The code below does what I want

```
 <?php if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my-tag-slug', true)) { ?><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my-tag-slug', true); ?><?php } else { ?><?php } ?>
```

but how can I put it here:

```
<?php

    $args=array(
      'tag' => 'tag-slug',
      'showposts'=>5,
      'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      echo '5 recent Posts with tag1';
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
       <?php
      endwhile;
    } //if ($my_query)
  wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

first get tag slug from your saved meta key my-tag-slug in a variable

```
$tag_slug = (isset(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my-tag-slug', true))) ? get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my-tag-slug', true) : null;
```

now query posts by $tag_slug replace showposts with posts_per_page

```
$args = array(
  'tag' => $tag_slug,
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'caller_get_posts' => 1
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  echo '5 recent Posts with tag1';
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
   <?php
  endwhile;
} //if ($my_query)
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: I placed the codes you provided in php tags, but they don't work. maybe I don't understand how to use them? to make it clear, 'my-tag-slug' is the custom field name, and $tag_slug must return the value for that custom field

Comment: any help please?

Comment: @whitelord why it's not working for you, are you getting any error?

Comment: @whitelord tag_slug is from your saved meta key, in 1st statement i am trying get tag slug from meta value if field is set otherwise return null, BTW where are you trying to `get_the_ID();` is this present?